# How can I find an appropriate image for a word on SRS?

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, spaced-repetition, anki

I'm writing a script that converts my list of bookmarked words into SRS, with audio and image on it. Now, I'm writing a script to fetch an image from Google Image, but the images I got are mostly useless.

For example, when I searched for an image on a French word *proviseur*, I got the following list, which is a good representation of the word (*principal*).

[image]

But when I searched for a word *nuire* (meaning *harm* as a verb), the result is useless, with the top result being the conjugation table of *nuire*.

[image]

Or when I searched for the word *fourni* (well-equipped), the result is full of an island called *fourni island*.

[image]

Unfortunately, the most words are much closer to the latter than the former, once you leap over the very basic words (such as *eat*, *dog*, etc...) (but the results of nouns usually work well).

So how can I make an appropriate image for my SRS?

Comment: You say that you are writing a script. Does that mean you want to *automate* the assignment of images?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Exactly, though I feel more and more like it is very difficult to implement.

Comment: Personally, I don't see how it can be done using just an algorithm (as opposed to AI). When I was creating Anki decks for Chinese, I often had difficulty finding an image that was sufficiently unambiguous. For example, an image that expresses the concept of "cold" when you also need flashcards for "snow" and "ice". Sometimes I put two images on the same flashcard for better disambiguation.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Initially I wrote a Python script that fetches images with the word and its language as input, but only found out that many images are not what I was looking for due the reasons I stated. Now I consider only automating the process of opening the search result of the image and saving it, while I choose the image manually.

Comment: For verbs, you might start with an example sentence. The more abstract a verb is, the harder it will be to visualize in a picture. For your example, I looked in a dictionary and found this example sentence: "L'alcool nuit à la santé." The idea of that sentence as a whole is probably easily visualized with a picture, but it's probably not something you could do with a script (you'd have to select the image that best evokes that idea).